# JPA - Mapping a join of 3 tables with an extra column on the join table with spring data

Tags: hibernate, jpa, database-design, spring-data

I'm having a hard time trying to map an optimal database design (using BCNF) to JPA entities.

I have 3 entities: Place, Person and Action.
On a given place, you have people performing actions, and we also have the number of times they performed the action there.

Note that each entity can exist independently: you can have a place with no actions executed, a person not executing any actions and actions not executed by anyone.

In order to store that information, I modeled the database schema as this:

[image: DB design]

Now I'm trying to create the JPA entities to map that, and that's where I'm having problems.
I would like to traverse the objects starting at the place, from the fetched place to be able to iterate through all the people executing actions in it, and finally for each person to be able to see what actions they executed **in that place** and how many times they did it.

From a pure SQL perspective it's easy enough:

Fetch the list of people on that place:

- select distinct(pe.name) from Place pl, Person pe, ActionPerformed ap where ap.place_id = pl.id and ap.person_id = pe.id and pl.id = <*place id*>

Then, for each person returned:

- select a.name, ap.count from Place pl, Person pe, Action a, ActionPerformed ap where ap.place_id = pl.id and ap.person_id = pe.id and ap.action_id = a.id and pl.id = <*place id*> and pe.id = <*person id*>

I would like to map that in JPA entities using that sort of drill down behavior:

- have an entity for Place, with a list of People that executed actions in it
- in the Person entity, have a list of Actions with their respective counts in that Place

Is that something possible to do with JPA? Or am I thinking the wrong way?

This was my attempt on the entities:

Starting with places, referencing people:

```
public class Place implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
        name="ActionPerformed"
        , joinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="place_id", nullable=false)
            }
        , inverseJoinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="person_id", nullable=false)
            }
        )
    private List<Person> people;

    <getters, setters, etc...>
}
```

Then people, referencing performed actions (with counts):

```
public class Person implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="person", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<ActionPerformed> actionsPerformed;

    <getters, setters, etc...>
}
```

The actions, mainly for their names:

```
public class Action implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    <getters, setters, etc...>
}
```

And the join table and PK object to associate all of them:

```
@Entity
public class ActionPerformed implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private ActionPerformedPK pk;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private Integer count;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="place_id")
    private Place place;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="person_id")
    private Person person;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="action_id")
    private Action action;

    <getters, setters, etc...>
}

@Embeddable
public class ActionPerformedPK implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="place_id")
    private Integer placeId;

    @Column(name="person_id")
    private Integer personId;

    @Column(name="action_id")
    private Integer actionId;

    <getters, setters, etc...>
}
```

One problem I'm seeing is when I query for a place, I get multiple entries for each person executing actions there - one per entry in the join table.
Moreover, when checking the actions listed in each person, I get all the actions performed by that person on every place (it is disregarding the place that originated the query).

Is there a way to fix this in the JPA mappings or entities design? Or would I have to change the database design?

P.S.: I have checked at least a dozen posts with questions similar to this, but none of them completely matched the design I'm attempting, so solutions proposed there din't work in my case.

P.S.2: I'm using Spring Data and CrudRepositories for creating the repositories from the entities.

P.S.3: Excuse me for bad grammar or "weird" sentences, english is not my native language.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked your code line by line, as I think your concerns aren't answered by the database design and class annotations but by the query.

If you want all action performances done by Bill in London, just write something like

```
select ap from ActionPerformance ap where ap.person.name = "Bill" and ap.place.name = "London"
```

and JPQL will generate some SQL similar to what you described from that.

Comment: Hi Tam, thanks for your comment!  What I was looking for, though, was a way to navigate through the entities using the repositories automatically generated by Spring Data.  With that, by merely creating the interfaces for the JPA I was hoping I would be able to navigate through the objects. In the end, a Place object could even be returned directly from a REST api GET method to return the whole hierarchy.